# Android Multi-touch not working properly

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, multi-touch

I am designing virtual buttons for a game based on surfaceview in android. I have overridden the onTouch(MotionEvent event) method to carry out the multitouch functions but it doesn't behaves the way I want it to. When one finger is touched, the second finger does not gets recognized and hence I am not able to perform the functions as desired. This is the code for the method that I had overridden.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    touchX = (int)event.getX();
    touchY = (int)event.getY();

    int action = event.getActionMasked();//event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

    if(touchX >= 0 && touchX <= leftbutton.getWidth() && touchY >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY <= this.getHeight()){
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            starship.setLeftRight(1, 0, true);
            leftButton.update(touchedleftbutton);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            leftButton.update(leftbutton);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
            starship.setLeftRight(1, 0, true);
            leftButton.update(touchedleftbutton);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){

            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            leftButton.update(leftbutton);
        }
    }
    else if (touchX >= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() && touchX <= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() + rightbutton.getWidth() && touchY >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY <= this.getHeight()){
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            starship.setLeftRight(0, 1, true);
            rightButton.update(touchedrightbutton);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            rightButton.update(rightbutton);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
            starship.setLeftRight(0, 1, true);
            rightButton.update(touchedrightbutton);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){
            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            rightButton.update(rightbutton);
        }
    }

    else if(touchX >= this.getWidth() - shootbutton.getWidth() && touchY >+ this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY < this.getHeight()){
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            shootButton.update(shoottouched);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            shootButton.update(shootbutton);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){

            shootButton.update(shoottouched);
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){

            shootButton.update(shootbutton);
        }
    }

    return true;        
}
```

----------------------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------------

I was able to solve my problem and everything's working fine now. Here's my updated code. Hope it helps anyone suffering from the same problem as me.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    int action = event.getActionMasked();//event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
    int pointerID = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

    touchX = new int[pointerCount];
    touchY = new int[pointerCount];

    for(int i = 0; i<pointerCount; i++){

        touchX[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
        touchY[i] = (int) event.getY(i);

    }
    switch(action){

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(touchX[0] >= 0 && touchX[0] <= leftbutton.getWidth() && touchY[0] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[0] <= this.getHeight()){
            starship.setLeftRight(1, 0, true);
            leftButton.update(touchedleftbutton);

        }
        else if (touchX[0] >= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() && touchX[0] <= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() + rightbutton.getWidth() && touchY[0] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[0] <= this.getHeight()){

            starship.setLeftRight(0, 1, true);
            rightButton.update(touchedrightbutton);
        }
        else if(touchX[0] >= this.getWidth() - shootbutton.getWidth() && touchY[0] >+ this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[0] < this.getHeight()){
            shootButton.update(shoottouched);
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if(touchX[0] >= 0 && touchX[0] <= leftbutton.getWidth() && touchY[0] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[0] <= this.getHeight()){
            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            leftButton.update(leftbutton);

        }
        else if (touchX[0] >= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() && touchX[0] <= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() + rightbutton.getWidth() && touchY[0] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[0] <= this.getHeight()){

            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            rightButton.update(rightbutton);
        }
        else if(touchX[0] >= this.getWidth() - shootbutton.getWidth() && touchY[0] >+ this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[0] < this.getHeight()){
            shootButton.update(shootbutton);
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        if(touchX[pointerID] >= 0 && touchX[pointerID] <= leftbutton.getWidth() && touchY[pointerID] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[pointerID] <= this.getHeight()){
            starship.setLeftRight(1, 0, true);
            leftButton.update(touchedleftbutton);

        }
        else if (touchX[pointerID] >= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() && touchX[pointerID] <= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() + rightbutton.getWidth() && touchY[pointerID] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[pointerID] <= this.getHeight()){

            starship.setLeftRight(0, 1, true);
            rightButton.update(touchedrightbutton);
        }
        else if(touchX[pointerID] >= this.getWidth() - shootbutton.getWidth() && touchY[pointerID] >+ this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[pointerID] < this.getHeight()){
            shootButton.update(shoottouched);
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        if(touchX[pointerID] >= 0 && touchX[pointerID] <= leftbutton.getWidth() && touchY[pointerID] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[pointerID] <= this.getHeight()){
            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            leftButton.update(leftbutton);

        }
        else if (touchX[pointerID] >= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() && touchX[pointerID] <= 20 + leftbutton.getWidth() + rightbutton.getWidth() && touchY[pointerID] >= this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[pointerID] <= this.getHeight()){

            starship.setLeftRight(0, 0, false);
            rightButton.update(rightbutton);
        }
        else if(touchX[pointerID] >= this.getWidth() - shootbutton.getWidth() && touchY[pointerID] >+ this.getHeight() - 100 && touchY[pointerID] < this.getHeight()){
            shootButton.update(shootbutton);
        }

        break;
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: It would help if you summarized the changes you made.

Answer (score 2):

My experience coding Android's multitouch and testing in a nexus one was depressing.

I ended up using [android-multitouch-controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/). That library will give you a better idea of how to handle all the caveats.

Comment: When I place 3 fingers (or more) on to the screen my code is ignored. I have some code that tracks a circle on screen where you touch. as Soon as the third is touched. No matter what you do it just stops following. Even if you lift 1 or 2 fingers off leaving 2 or 1 finger. And the Major problem is that sometimes it classes 1 finger as 3. So it will freeze randomly.